# Permanent Redirect without htaccess to readable SEO URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, duplicates

I am about to change some of my URLs from `details.html?id=1234` to `details/1234_really_interesting_stuff`. The ID 1234 will be used to identify the content, `really_interesting_stuff` is just to make the URLs more readable.

In the next step, I will replace all the links on my website referring to `details.html?id=1234` with the new URL where `really_interesting_stuff` is stored in the database. The problem I'm facing now: how can I make a google-friendly 301-redirect such that I won't have duplicate content (because google will still now old links such as `details.html?id=1234` which are also spread on other webpages). I'll have to forward to `details/1234_really_interesting_stuff`. Unfortunately, the string is only kept in the database.

As far as I know, the only google-friendly 301-redirect is a htaccess-file. But there is no way to retrieve the information from the database in an htaccess-file. How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know, the only google-friendly 301-redirect is a htaccess-file.

That's incorrect, and Google has no means to divine how you're doing your 301s anyway.

You can do your redirections dynamically. Ex (in PHP) :

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.tld/details/1234_really_interesting_stuff");
echo "<html><body>The page has moved <a href="http://www.yourwebsite.tld/details/1234_really_interesting_stuff">here.</a></body></html>" ;
```

The reason for the HTML snippet is described [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to place in in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one with 302
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+details\.html\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ /details/%1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^details/([^/.]+)/?$ /details.html?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Then inside `details.html` you can check whether title is supplied in `$_GET['id']` OR not, if not then query database and append title in URL using `header` function.